# MatLab Formatting to 8 decimal places not working

Tags: matlab, decimal

```
alice_accel = readFile('Alice_Accel.txt')
bob_accel = readFile('Bob_Accel.txt')

% ======================== Functions =========================== %

% File reader routine. Takes parameter as file name.
function    reader  = readFile( name )
    fid = fopen( name );
    % Formatted file as: x, y, z <NEWLINE>
    reader = textscan(fid, '%.8f%.8f%.8f', 'CollectOutput', true ...
                                  , 'Delimiter'    , ','  ); 
    fclose( fid );
end
```

Hi, this is my code, and I am trying to read a comma-separated value file, and that works fine when I don't have `%.8f` and use `%f`, but it only gives me 4 decimal places, I need all 8. How do I make this function work?

Edit: this is an example data file

```
0.54859161, -0.67505932, 0.28296280, 
0.56373024, -0.67847729, 0.29565811, 
0.55933380, -0.68238354, 0.28100967, 
0.55933380, -0.68238354, 0.28100967, 
0.56519508, -0.68336010, 0.27222061, 
0.56568336, -0.68628979, 0.28491592, 
0.55640411, -0.68384838, 0.28686905, 
0.55640411, -0.68384838, 0.28686905, 
0.55054474, -0.69800854, 0.26440811, 
0.53589630, -0.69507885, 0.27612686, 
0.55103302, -0.70093822, 0.27661514, 
0.55103302, -0.70093822, 0.27661514, 
0.56714821, -0.69996166, 0.26343155, 
0.56812477, -0.69605541, 0.25561905, 
0.56812477, -0.69605541, 0.25561905, 
0.55152130, -0.69800854, 0.27075577, 
0.55152130, -0.70386791, 0.28296280, 
0.55591583, -0.70582104, 0.27612686, 
0.55152130, -0.69947338, 0.28052139, 
0.55152130, -0.69947338, 0.28052139, 
0.56079865, -0.70142651, 0.27075577, 
0.54175568, -0.70582104, 0.27856827, 
0.54175568, -0.70582104, 0.27856827, 
0.55054474, -0.69507885, 0.27319717, 
0.56714821, -0.69898510, 0.27905655, 
0.56226349, -0.70386791, 0.28540421, 
0.57105446, -0.70386791, 0.28247452, 
0.56714821, -0.70484447, 0.27954483, 
0.56714821, -0.70484447, 0.27954483, 
0.56617165, -0.69117260, 0.28686905, 
0.56665993, -0.69654369, 0.27612686, 
0.56665993, -0.69654369, 0.27612686, 
0.56617165, -0.69214916, 0.27807999,
```

Comment: Are you sure `%f` does not work? By default Matlab only prints the first 4 decimal places. You can call `format long` too show more decimal places.

Comment: Since you're reading from a file, are you **sure** the values in the file have more than 4 decimal places?

Comment: yeah, they have 8 decimal points each. How do I call format long? Sorry, I'm newbie to matlab

Comment: I added format long as the first line of the script but it didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is the least helpful thing you could say. *What* doesn't work about it? What did you type? What did you see?

Comment: I just typed format long both in the command line then ran the program. I also added it as the first line in my code (above). The output was the same, all the decimals in the matrix were 4 dp.

Comment: How exactly are you determining that the "decimals in the matrix are 4 dp"?

Comment: Can you provide us a sample data file and the commands you use to visualise the data?

Comment: Hi, I look at the matrix using the Matlab interface to open "alice_accel" by double clicking the variable on the right hand side. I will add a data file to my main post.

Comment: @Display: I got exactly what you want running that code with that sample data. After loading it (as 'Alice_Accel.txt'), type this: `format long; alice_accel{1}`. You will see what you want. Closing as dupe.